# How to package my python program so the user can install it using setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a single python file right now and I am asked to convert it into a python module where the user can install it using python setup.py install. I am not sure how to do that. I have followed some instructions online and created the setup.py file and the init.py file. The setup.py file looks like this:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

I am not sure if this setup.py file is correct.Also I don't know what I am supposed to do next. Can anyone help me and tell me what am I supposed to do? Is there tutorial that teaches this? I can't really find anything related. Also is my setup.py correct? Thanks!

Comment: For a single Python file you don't need `packages`, you need `py_modules=['thefile'],` (put module name, i.e. filename without extensions `.py`). Everything else looks good.

Comment: For docs on packaging and distributing start at https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/ and https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/

Comment: There are plenty of resources available on packaging Python programs, including the official [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/#), in what way are these questions not already covered by those?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do packaging. [packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#packaging-python-projects) on python.org and [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#building-and-distributing-packages-with-setuptools) are a good start.

Unfortunately, examples tend to focus on package distributions, not single modules. Instead of `packages`, use the `py_modules` keyword. Assuming your module is called "test.py", this setup.py will work

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="test",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description="",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    py_modules = ["test"],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

If you think this will expand to multiple modules, then you can go back to using 
`setuptools.find_packages()`. In this case, you want a subdirectory named after your desired package and put the init in there

```
some_random_project_file
    +-- setup.py
        README.md
        LICENCE
    +-- test
        +-- __init__.py
            test.py
```

Comment: Good answer, I think I would have avoided the name `test` though, since such files and directories could be handled somewhat differently, depending on context (automatically added to `MANIFEST`, automatically looked up by _unittest_).

Comment: Good answer. When I'm using py_modules keyword, does arg `name` in setup func must be 'test'? How about name='a' and py_modules=['b'] ?

Comment: @Anthony - "test" is just a stand-in for your distirbution name. "test" would be a bad cnoice! Typically, when distributing a single module, `name` would be the same as the single item in the `py_modules` list. But it could be anything you want. `name` names the distribution package, `py_modules` names the modules included in the distribution.